# can we login with other user id without password

Tags: user

Can any one let me know.Can we login with other user id without password.These two users are of different orgs.

1)One of the client states that the other company I work with requested access to my account as a support administrator.  I grant access from this request.

Correct me if im wrong:As per my understanding,this client has given an "grant access permission to login with his user id without password".Or Do we have any other option where we can login.

2)we need to create an a/c in that give his user id .

Answer (score 0):

If both users are in the same org we can grant access.
we can also grant access to the salesforce support.
But,
In your case after looking at your statement both users are in different orgs, its better you refer the salesforce Grant login access manual to get more clear idea. 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003910&language=en_US